# Is there a way to modify TeamCity system properties in a shell script?

Tags: shell, powershell, teamcity

I'm trying to figure out how to modify some custom system properties that I've defined in the build configurations parameters.

For example, if I have a system property named `system.TestProperty` with value 0 and I want to modify it's value from shell, I've tryed using `##teamcity[setParameter name='system.TestProperty' value='1']` as explained [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-AddingorChangingaBuildParameter) but the next time I get it's value, it gives me 0 again.
The script i'm using to test:

```
Write-Host "-------------"
$testProperty = "%system.TestProperty%"
Write-Host "system.TestProperty: $testProperty"

Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='system.TestProperty' value='1']"

$testProperty = "%system.TestProperty%"
Write-Host "system.TestProperty: $testProperty"
Write-Host "-------------"
```

What I'm getting:

```
-------------
system.TestProperty: 0
##teamcity[setParameter name='system.TestProperty' value='1']
system.TestProperty: 0
-------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wont see the parameter updated in the same script. If you split the check into another build step, you should see it there.